# Oracle development tools for visual studio not installing

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2013, oracle11g, odp.net

I'm new to Oracle. I need to use Oracle 11g R2 with .net framework 4. I have installed oracle and ODT for VS on my machine, but I'm not able to connect with oracle in visual studio.When I go to server explorer in VS to add connection and change the data source, I don't see Oracle Database(ODT.NET, Managed Driver) to connect which is selected in the following tutorial.
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/EntityFrameworkOBE_2/EntityFrameworkOBE.html#overview

I have installed both express edition of oracle and complete one too. I'm using windows 7 and visual studio 2013.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you very much it helped but now when I'm trying to connect, I'm this error:  ora-12545 network transport: unable to resolve connect hostname

Comment: What is your connection string? Maybe open a new question for this.

Comment: This is the connection string :( DATA SOURCE=MyDB;USER ID=AHSEN

Comment: Did you install ODTwithODAC121021.zip from here? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html If not please install it.